Ansible AWX install: cannot create directory '/var/lib/pgsql/data/userdata': Permission denied
I am getting a permision denied message although I checked and the directory is owned by root.
I have installed Ansible AWX as below:
helm install my-awx-operator awx-operator/awx-operator -n awx --create-namespace


Output:
:~/dev/awx # helm list -n awx
NAME            NAMESPACE       REVISION        UPDATED                                 STATUS          CHART                   APP VERSION
my-awx-operator awx             1               2024-10-25 16:06:52.124682142 +0000 UTC deployed        awx-operator-2.19.1     2.19.1
:~/dev/awx #

:~/dev/awx # kubectl get pv
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS      CLAIM                                       STORAGECLASS             REASON   AGE
ansible1-awx-pv                            12Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound       awx/postgres-15-ansible-awx-postgres-15-0   global-data-sc                13m

:~/dev/awx # kubectl get pvc -n awx
NAME                                    STATUS   VOLUME            CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS         AGE
postgres-15-ansible-awx-postgres-15-0   Bound    ansible1-awx-pv   12Gi       RWO            global-data-sc   12m
:~/dev/awx #

---
# Redis DB persistence/dump data
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: ansible1-awx-pv
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 12Gi
  hostPath:
    path: /root/awx
    type: DirectoryOrCreate
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: global-data-sc
  volumeMode: Filesystem
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: postgres-15-ansible-awx-postgres-15-0
  namespace: awx
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: global-data-sc
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  volumeName: ansible1-awx-pv
---
apiVersion: awx.ansible.com/v1beta1
kind: AWX
metadata:
  name: ansible-awx
  namespace: awx
spec:
  service_type: nodeport
  postgres_storage_class: global-data-sc


I am getting the following error:
:~/dev/awx # kubectl get pods -n awx
NAME                                               READY   STATUS             RESTARTS        AGE
ansible-awx-postgres-15-0                          0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   7 (3m14s ago)   14m
awx-operator-controller-manager-5ccb88d675-wxx89   2/2     Running            0               3d
:~/dev/awx #

:~/dev/awx # kubectl logs -n awx ansible-awx-postgres-15-0
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/pgsql/data/userdata': Permission denied
:~/dev/awx #

:~/dev/awx # ls -ltr /root/
total 148820
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root      4096 Oct 28 14:59 awx
:~/dev/awx #


:~/dev/awx # ls -ltr /root/awx/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 28 14:59 data
:~/dev/awx #


What am I missing?

The main reason for the permission denied error is that, kubernetes pods: postgres pod is running as non root user. That's why it can't write to directory which is owned by root (postgres as non root user can't have write access)
You need to set proper permission on hostpath dir.
Update the ownership as following:
sudo chown -R 26:26 /root/awx   # postgres in k8s uses uid: 26 and gid: 26 

Also you can double check for PersistentVolume as following:
spec:
 hostPath:
  path: /root/awx
  type: DirectoryOrCreate  # => creates dir if not exist 

After changes, delete the postgres pod and create again
kubectl delete pod -n awx ansible-awx-postgres-15-0
kubectl get pods -n awx    # check status

Here you can also read about Kubernetes docs on hostPath volumes
